# Selecting some text under an element

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I am trying to select the text in the following table

```
<section id="bullet_features">
<h2>Additional Features</h2>
<p>
Knife Steel: 8Cr13MoV, satin finish
<br>
Handle: Molded co-polymer
<br>
Blade: 3.6 in.
<br>
Overall: 8 in.
</p>
</section>
```

I am able to grab the entire "bullet_features" box, but I want to specifically grab one line at a time. for example, I want one xpath expression to point to:

```
Knife Steel: 8Cr13MoV, satin finish
```

and another to point to:

```
Handle: Molded co-polymer
```

my current expression:

```
//*[@id="bullet_features"]
```

grabs it all, I have tried `following-sibling` and `/text()` but its not working in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//*[@id="bullet_features"]/p/text()[1]
```

will select

```
Knife Steel: 8Cr13MoV, satin finish
```

and this XPath,

```
//*[@id="bullet_features"]/p/text()[2]
```

will select

```
Handle: Molded co-polymer
```

as requested.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
it doesn't seem to work for me still though. The table is located on this website: 

     https://kershaw.kaiusaltd.com/knives/knife/1028grn-zipit-grn-combo-pack

and applying the provided XPATH doesn't return the whitespace text

Comment: What do you mean by "whitespace text"?

Comment: As in text that isn't bordered by an element in HTML

Comment: That's a non-standard and confusingly applied phrase.  You can see from [this demo](http://xpather.com/xVOnuaX8) that the XPaths I provided do select the requested text.   Your [mcve] wasn't representative of your actual case.  Your actual case has multiple `p` elements.  You can similarly select between them via an index, e.g: `//*[@id="bullet_features"]/p[1]/text()[1]`